# Corresponding element in arrays

Tags: java, swing, tic-tac-toe

I was wondering what **Create a JLabel object using new, and place it in the corresponding element in the array. (grid[row][col])** means. I am creating a Tic-Tac-Toe program.I am using a for loop to initialize the grid.
here's what I have for the for loop:

```
package tic.tac.toe;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class TicTacToe extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener
{
 Container content = this.getContentPane();
 //Program Arrays
JLabel [][] grid = new JLabel[' '][' '];
char [][ ]game = new char [' '][' '];
// Graphical User-interface Fields
JButton restart = new JButton("Restart");
JPanel p = new JPanel();
JLabel status = new JLabel("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe");
//Primitive Fields
int numClicks = 0 ;
boolean isDone = false;
boolean isXTurn = true;

public TicTacToe()
{//GUI
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    this.setSize(900,500);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //SetLayout

    //Add Status Label
    content.add(status);
    status.setOpaque(true);
    status.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    status.setForeground(Color.blue);
    status.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 12));
    //Initailize the Main Panel
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    p.setBackground(Color.black);
    content.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //Initialize the grid
    for(int row = 0; row<=3;)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col<=3;)
        {
           JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
           grid[row][col] = lbl;
           grid[row][col].addMouseListener(this);
           grid[row][col].setOpaque(true);
           grid[row][col].setBackground(Color.white);
           grid[row][col].setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 39));
           p.add(grid[row][col]);



        }
    }

}





@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
{

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
{

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
{

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) 
{

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) 
{

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) 
{

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    TicTacToe tTT = new TicTacToe();
}
```

}

Comment: What is you question, it is unclear to me

Comment: This is clearly homework help, and you've put forth zero effort.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I didn't want to put the whole code in because its too long but here is what I actually have

Comment: `public class TicTacToe extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener` This is not OO. And what is your question?

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Its one of the teacher's guide lines and my Question is how do  I create a JLabel using new and place it to the corresponding element in the grid array that's in the field.

Comment: This is not a homework help site. You haven't written any code of your own. If you don't know what **create a JLabel using new** means, I doubt anyone's going to rush to your aid.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I know it means JLabel lbl = new JLabel(); but i have to add an array to that which gives me an error.. I' just stuck on this one step thats all

Comment: By the way, there is a huge problem here. `new char[' '][' ']` is pretty dangerous. That is the same as saying `new char[32][32]`, but in a very unclear way. And for example, `new int['1']` has a length of `49`. I am not sure if this is intended behavior, but that is terrifying to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you some hints, otherwise it won't help you I would do your homework :

1. Arrays in Java are defined this way : `Type[] varName = new Type[NumberOfOccurences];` OR more dimensions `Type[][] varName = new Type[NumberOfOccurencesForDimension1][NumberOfOccurencesForDimension2];`.
2. Putting a table into an array of one dimension needs to calculate its index by `myArray[rowIndex * colIndex + colIndex] = objectToPutIn;`
3. Putting a table into an array of two dimensions is trivial : `myArray[rowIndex][colIndex] = objectToPutIn;`
4. Array index in Java starts at 0. So an array of one element is at index 0.

Comment: Oh By the way, I had my original code right, its just that one of my cells is larger than the others...